# send UIImage from one class to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

i want to send UIImage from one class to another .
In FirstViewController.m i wrote this code

```
 FormViewController *formViewController =[[FormViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FormViewController" bundle:nil];
formViewController.userImage=imageFb;
    [formViewController.userImage retain];
 [self presentModalViewController:formViewController animated:YES];
```

the error is

> Request for member 'userImage' is something not a structure or union

In FormViewController.h

```
@interface FormViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *photo;
    UIimage *userImage;

}
@property(retain,nonatomic)  UIimage *userImage;
@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photo;
```

and i get this error

> expected specifier-qualifier-list before UIimage

in FormViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    [photo setImage:userImage];
}
```

and the error is

> userImage undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `UIImage`, not `UIimage`.

Answer (score 0):

convert image in `NSData`
than assign the `NSData` object to the another class property of type `NSData`

```
NSData *imgdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(topImage, 1.0);
```

then convert that `NSData` property in to image by following way

```
imageview.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgdata];
```